When is it appropriate to suggest a nonpreferred reviewer?
I submitted a manuscript to a journal and got desk rejected by the editor who also gave feedback on why the manuscript was rejected. We made changes to address this feedback but after some back and forth with the editor they did not send the paper for additional peer review. My supervisor believes that the paper should have at least been sent out for additional review after we addressed the editors comments. So, after some more changes we are submitting the paper to a new journal.
What is the main purpose of suggesting a nonpreferred reviewer? Would it be inappropriate to suggest the editor who previously rejected the paper as a nonpreferred reviewer even though we have no "conflict of interest" with them?

Seems unlikely that journal editors do much reviewing for other journals, but I could well be wrong since I’ve never been an editor.

Related: Sound reasons for excluding a reviewer, Who should be excluded from reviewing

(1) It's already uncommon to be able to resubmit a desk rejected paper. Most desk rejections are just that, not desk reject and resubmits. (2) By "nonpreferred reviewer" you mean someone that you actively do not want to review, right? The wording could imply someone you are indifferent about. That said, I believe most systems do not ask you the reasons why you would want to exclude someone, so just go ahead and do so.

@StephanKolassa That looks like an answer, not a comment.

@ChristianHennig: ... but thanks to you, I don't need to post it any more! Thank you!

@JonCuster: "Seems unlikely that journal editors do much reviewing for other journals" I'm not sure I follow. Being an editor is usually just one obligation among many others (except maybe for some editors-in-chief). Why would it prevent someone from reviewing for other journals?

@JochenGlueck - it seems to me that being an editor for a journal is already much more work than a reviewer puts in, so volunteering further time to review for other journals is just piling obligation on obligation. Then, and this is a personal feeling, reviewing for another journal raises potential conflicts of interest - should I recommend rejection of this paper and hope it comes to my journal... But I've never been a journal editor.

@JonCuster: In my experience this is not an issue at all. I'm on the editorial board of two journals (for one/two years) and handling a submission is way less work than reviewing it. (But as I said, the work load is certainly much higher for editors-in-chief.) The idea that I could stop reviewing for other journals has never occurred to me. Similarly, the idea that I could, as a reviewer, recommend rejection of a good paper and hope that it is then submitted to a journal I'm involved with, has never occurred to me (and, no offence intended, the idea seems quite far fetched).

@JochenGlueck - perfect, word from someone with experience. Many thanks.


What is the main purpose of suggesting a nonpreferred reviewer?

If you believe there are reasons that certain reviewers may unfairly recommend to reject your work, you could name them as "nonpreferred" reviewers. This may be because of differences in "philosophy" (some people are against a whole direction of research whether well done or not), or because of certain experiences in the past (somebody may hold a grudge against you because you won a position or a grant against them and they may not have taken it well). You may also in a conference already have been unfairly criticised by them. As @StephanKolassa wrote in their comment, however, you will not normally need to give reasons why you nominate anybody.

Would it be inappropriate to suggest the editor who previously rejected the paper as a nonpreferred reviewer even though we have no "conflict of interest" with them?

I wouldn't say it's inappropriate, but chances are I wouldn't do that myself in this situation, unless the editor criticised your work in a really unfair manner and it seems realistic that they may be asked to review (which very often isn't the case).
My reasons are (a) in general I believe it looks better to not make any nomination of a nonpreferred reviewer, because by doing this you already tell editors that there may be people around who may not appreciate your work. This will not of course normally lead to rejection, but it does transport some (if weak) negativity regarding your own work. Also it restricts the editor's scope to find reviewers and may lead to delay in case the nonpreferred reviewer would otherwise have been a suitable candidate (in some cases a fast rejection is better than the process taking ages). Also the editor may in principle know and esteem this person, in which case it wouldn't reflect so well on you to exclude them as reviewer. So in my view there should be really strong reasons to nominate nonpreferred reviewers, otherwise I wouldn't do it (and if so minimise their number, optimally to zero or one if at all possible). Personally if I remember it correctly, I only did that once, for the "philosophical differences" reason mentioned above, and because I knew this person would be seen as a major option to review, and chances were that they would want to stop my work from being published.
(b) A desk rejection is a rejection and not normally meant to be discussed or challenged. The editor very often doesn't have enough time to write down all their reasons in detail, so it may not be the case that what you think you have addressed indeed addresses all reasons the editor had to reject your paper. In any case they may have so much to do that as a matter of principle papers rejected once are not considered again. The editor knows that there are other journals, so if you can improve your paper based on the editor's comments, you can well submit somewhere else. This means that what the editor did is normal editor's behaviour. It doesn't mean, in my view, that you were treated or assessed unfairly here  (of course I cannot have any idea whether their original arguments were fair, or what went on in later exchanges, which may imply a reason to "nonprefer" this person, but see above).

Can you clarify your (b)? The OP states that they are submitting to a new journal, so its not like they are asking for resubmission to a journal that has already rejected them. Do you mean that you don't think the editor necessarily doesn't like the paper just because they rejected it, and therefore shouldn't be excluded?

@IanSudbery I believe that the editor of the first journal behaved in a normal way that doesn't constitute any evidence that they would assess the paper unfairly if being a reviewer. Of course it could arguably be likely that they'd recommend to reject it, but I wouldn't take this as a given (of course we don't know the details of the earlier exchange, but they could well be OK with accepting this in another journal that they perceive as lower level). As said in (a) I wouldn't nominate as nonpreferred somebody just because there is a chance they may recommend to reject.
